# Get WIA scanner features

Tags: c#, wia

How do you get a scanner's available resolutions and/or dpi.   Also, how to get the information that it has an automatic document feeder, etc?

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve the features available for your scanner by navigating through the Properties object like Matthias suggested to you.
Here is an enum I use with all the properties and their IDs:

```
public enum WiaProperty
{
    DeviceId = 2,
    Manufacturer = 3,
    Description = 4,
    Type = 5,
    Port = 6,
    Name = 7,
    Server = 8,
    RemoteDevId = 9,
    UIClassId = 10,
    FirmwareVersion = 1026,
    ConnectStatus = 1027,
    DeviceTime = 1028,
    PicturesTaken = 2050,
    PicturesRemaining = 2051,
    ExposureMode = 2052,
    ExposureCompensation = 2053,
    ExposureTime = 2054,
    FNumber = 2055,
    FlashMode = 2056,
    FocusMode = 2057,
    FocusManualDist = 2058,
    ZoomPosition = 2059,
    PanPosition = 2060,
    TiltPostion = 2061,
    TimerMode = 2062,
    TimerValue = 2063,
    PowerMode = 2064,
    BatteryStatus = 2065,
    Dimension = 2070,
    HorizontalBedSize = 3074,
    VerticalBedSize = 3075,
    HorizontalSheetFeedSize = 3076,
    VerticalSheetFeedSize = 3077,
    SheetFeederRegistration = 3078,         // 0 = LEFT_JUSTIFIED, 1 = CENTERED, 2 = RIGHT_JUSTIFIED
    HorizontalBedRegistration = 3079,       // 0 = LEFT_JUSTIFIED, 1 = CENTERED, 2 = RIGHT_JUSTIFIED
    VerticalBedRegistraion = 3080,          // 0 = TOP_JUSTIFIED, 1 = CENTERED, 2 = BOTTOM_JUSTIFIED
    PlatenColor = 3081,
    PadColor = 3082,
    FilterSelect = 3083,
    DitherSelect = 3084,
    DitherPatternData = 3085,

    DocumentHandlingCapabilities = 3086,    // FEED = 0x01, FLAT = 0x02, DUP = 0x04, DETECT_FLAT = 0x08, 
                                            // DETECT_SCAN = 0x10, DETECT_FEED = 0x20, DETECT_DUP = 0x40, 
                                            // DETECT_FEED_AVAIL = 0x80, DETECT_DUP_AVAIL = 0x100
    DocumentHandlingStatus = 3087,          // FEED_READY = 0x01, FLAT_READY = 0x02, DUP_READY = 0x04, 
                                            // FLAT_COVER_UP = 0x08, PATH_COVER_UP = 0x10, PAPER_JAM = 0x20
    DocumentHandlingSelect = 3088,          // FEEDER = 0x001, FLATBED = 0x002, DUPLEX = 0x004, FRONT_FIRST = 0x008
                                            // BACK_FIRST = 0x010, FRONT_ONLY = 0x020, BACK_ONLY = 0x040
                                            // NEXT_PAGE = 0x080, PREFEED = 0x100, AUTO_ADVANCE = 0x200
    DocumentHandlingCapacity = 3089, 
    HorizontalOpticalResolution = 3090,
    VerticalOpticalResolution = 3091,
    EndorserCharacters = 3092,
    EndorserString = 3093,
    ScanAheadPages = 3094,                  // ALL_PAGES = 0
    MaxScanTime = 3095,
    Pages = 3096,                           // ALL_PAGES = 0
    PageSize = 3097,                        // A4 = 0, LETTER = 1, CUSTOM = 2
    PageWidth = 3098,
    PageHeight = 3099,
    Preview = 3100,                         // FINAL_SCAN = 0, PREVIEW = 1
    TransparencyAdapter = 3101,
    TransparecnyAdapterSelect = 3102,
    ItemName = 4098,
    FullItemName = 4099,
    ItemTimeStamp = 4100,
    ItemFlags = 4101,
    AccessRights = 4102,
    DataType = 4103,
    BitsPerPixel = 4104,
    PreferredFormat = 4105,
    Format = 4106,
    Compression = 4107,                     // 0 = NONE, JPG = 5, PNG = 8
    MediaType = 4108,
    ChannelsPerPixel = 4109,
    BitsPerChannel = 4110,
    Planar = 4111,
    PixelsPerLine = 4112,
    BytesPerLine = 4113,
    NumberOfLines = 4114,
    GammaCurves = 4115,
    ItemSize = 4116,
    ColorProfiles = 4117,
    BufferSize = 4118,
    RegionType = 4119,
    ColorProfileName = 4120,
    ApplicationAppliesColorMapping = 4121,
    StreamCompatibilityId = 4122,
    ThumbData = 5122,
    ThumbWidth = 5123,
    ThumbHeight = 5124,
    AudioAvailable = 5125,
    AudioFormat = 5126,
    AudioData = 5127,
    PicturesPerRow = 5128,
    SequenceNumber = 5129,
    TimeDelay = 5130,
    CurrentIntent = 6146,
    HorizontalResolution = 6147,
    VerticalResolution = 6148,
    HorizontalStartPosition = 6149,
    VerticalStartPosition = 6150,
    HorizontalExtent = 6151,
    VerticalExtent = 6152,
    PhotometricInterpretation = 6153,
    Brightness = 6154,
    Contrast = 6155,
    Orientation = 6156, // 0 = PORTRAIT, 1 = LANDSCAPE, 2 = 180°, 3 = 270°
    Rotation = 6157, // 0 = PORTRAIT, 1 = LANDSCAPE, 2 = 180°, 3 = 270°
    Mirror = 6158,
    Threshold = 6159,
    Invert = 6160,
    LampWarmUpTime = 6161,
}
```

For the possible values of every single property you can read the MSDN documentation:

[MSDN WIA Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

or if you want to get deeper, you can analyze the header files of the original SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Properties object containing a list of properties. Use the Properties object of the Device object to access scanner properties (document feeder), use the Properties object of the Item object to access page properties (resolution).

Here is some code:

```
        DeviceManager manager = new DeviceManagerClass();
        DeviceInfo scannerInfo = WiaHelper.FindFirstScanner(manager);
        Device device = scannerInfo.Connect();
        Item item = device.Items[1];

    public static DeviceInfo FindFirstScanner(DeviceManager manager)
    {
        DeviceInfos infos = manager.DeviceInfos;
        foreach (DeviceInfo info in infos)
            if (info.Type == WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
                return info;
        return null;
    }

    public static Property FindProperty(WIA.Properties properties, int propertyId)
    {
        foreach (Property property in properties)
            if (property.PropertyID == propertyId)
                return property;
        return null;
    }

    public static void SetDeviceProperty(Device device, int propertyId, object value)
    {
        Property property = FindProperty(device.Properties, propertyId);
        if (property != null)
            property.set_Value(value);
    }

    public static object GetDeviceProperty(Device device, int propertyId)
    {
        Property property = FindProperty(device.Properties, propertyId);
        return property != null ? property.get_Value() : null;
    }

    public static object GetItemProperty(Item item, int propertyId)
    {
        Property property = FindProperty(item.Properties, propertyId);
        return property != null ? property.get_Value() : null;
    }

    public static void SetItemProperty(Item item, int propertyId, object value)
    {
        Property property = FindProperty(item.Properties, propertyId);
        if (property != null)
            property.set_Value(value);
    }
```